# Azure Synapse Analytics vs Google Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, azure-synapse

Data is stored in form of json files(millions of json files with same structure) in Azure Blob storage container. Right now HdInsight service is used to load the data from the containers and process the data .

Now we want to switch to Azure Synapse analytics or Big Query to to take the advantage of parallel processing and writing sql like queries which can give faster response on the data

Data is in TBs right now.

Can any one suggest which would be better.

Answer (score 0):

The straight-forward answer is to use Azure Synapse Analytics because you are already using Azure Blob Storage service. You can directly link the Azure Blob container with Synapse and Query the TBs of data without any issue as Synapse has auto scale-out feature.

On the other side if you will connect Blob Storage with Google BigQuery it will add middleware (another service like ADF) which will increase the architecture complexity.

Google BigQuery and Microsoft Azure Synapse Analytics have a lot in common, including columnar storage and massively parallel processing (MPP) architecture. But still if you interested to know the differences, **we can differentiate these two services on basis of Pricing, Architecture, Performance, Administration, Data protection and Security Compliances.**

Get the detailed differences between these two services [here](https://hevodata.com/learn/google-bigquery-vs-azure-synapse/#4).

Comment: You can directly query data from Blob Storage. refer https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/cloud/azure/query-blob-storage-sql-using-azure-synapse/

Comment: Hello @UtkarshPal-MT . Thanks for the inputs here and i reframed my query a bit

in my Azure blob container I  have data stored(of same structure) in form of json files and the data in json file format is [{},{}].

would it be better to write sql queries directly using  OPENROWSET( ) on Azure Blob or Create a pipeline to copy data to synapse dedicated pools and then query the data.

I have use  OPENROWSET function but getting some access issues but would it be ideal to go with sqlserverless pool rather then going with a dedicated pool.

Comment: yes you can use `OPENROWSET` even to query the JSON data using Synapse serverless SQL pool in Synapse. check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/query-json-files

Comment: hello @UtkarshPal-MT i looked at OPENROWSET function but i think the limitation is we need to provide the json files we want to query .

But in my scenario my blob container contains millions of json files , i want to run the query on all the files and filter out the data . Any help on this how to achieve the same.

Comment: You need to manage it programmatically. Create a list of all the files in container and then iterate over the list to work with each file.